# Python Pandas: Changing value of previous rows based on a later value (In a grouped/partitioned dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this dataframe:

| Timestamp | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1 | Direct |
| 00:10 | 1 | Something |
| 00:12 | 1 | Direct |
| 00:01 | 2 | Direct |
| 00:02 | 2 | Direct |
| 00:02 | 2 | Direct |
| 00:03 | 2 | Something |
| 00:03 | 3 | Direct |
| 00:03 | 3 | Direct |

I am trying to group the columns to unique ID's, which in itself is simple. My challenge is as follows:
If the latest (by Timestamp) Value column for a given ID is "Direct", the latest row and the following rows needs to be changed to the latest value which is NOT "Direct", for example "Something.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

| Timestamp | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 1 | Something |
| 00:10 | 1 | Something |
| 00:12 | 1 | Direct |
| 00:01 | 2 | Something |
| 00:02 | 2 | Something |
| 00:03 | 2 | Something |
| 00:03 | 3 | Direct |
| 00:03 | 3 | Direct |

This is something that is probably possible with Partition BY in SQL, but I have yet to figure it out in Pandas. I managed to do it with iterrows(), but as I have a rather large dataset, it is simply too slow.

Is there an effective way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: Do you think minimal time per groups?

Comment: What values are compared? Rows with `00:00` ? Or `00:12`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with custom function for replace only first group `Direct` values by previous values:

```
print (df)
  Timestamp  ID      Value
0     00:00   1  Something
1     00:10   1  Something
2     00:12   1  Something
3     01:01   1  Something
4     01:02   1     Direct
5     01:02   1        AAA
6     01:03   1     Direct
7     00:03   3     Direct
8     00:03   3     Direct

def f(x):
    m = x.ffill().isna()
    return x.mask(m, x.bfill())

df['Value'] = (df.assign(Value = df['Value'].replace('Direct', np.nan))
                 .groupby(df['ID'])['Value']
                 .transform(f)
                 .fillna('Direct')
                 )

print (df)
  Timestamp  ID      Value
0     00:00   1  Something
1     00:10   1  Something
2     00:12   1  Something
3     01:01   1  Something
4     01:02   1     Direct
5     01:02   1        AAA
6     01:03   1     Direct
7     00:03   3     Direct
8     00:03   3     Direct
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. The rows are indeed sorted. Your solution seems to work, but I see that my question has not been detailed enough. "Something" is just a generic value. It could be anything. Meaning that the "Direct" rows, needs to be changed to the latest value of that ID which is not "Direct".

Comment: Perhaps I have not explained the problem well enough. 'Last' does not filter like ".ne('Direct'), right? Meaning if ID1 has rows [Direct, Direct, Something1, Something2] All the rows (including Something1) get changed to Something2? In this particular situation I am trying to change Direct, Direct to Something1, and let Something2 be. I am simply trying to change all the latest Direct's if there is something else present following the Direct. If there are multiple following, pick the first one which is not direct

Comment: @Guttulsrud - Can you check another edit?

Comment: Does this discriminate on ID's which have the following rows: [Direct, Something1, Direct, Something2]? The desired output on this particular ID is [Something1, Something1, Direct, Something], as the "Direct" following the last valid Value should remain intact. I'm trying to understand the Pandas syntax, and it seems the last edit changes all of the Directs for a ID? Again, many thanks for you help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I have observed that it does indeed fill [Direct, Something1, Direct, Something2] to [Something1, Something1, Something1, Something2] instead of [Something1, Something1, Direct, Something2]. Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: @Guttulsrud - I am a bit confused, neech change `.bfill()` to `ffill()` ?

Comment: `Something1, Something1, Direct, Something` is in one group? Then for backfill is ouput `Something1, Something1, Something, Something`, for forward fill (ffill) is output ``Something1, Something1, Something1, Something``

Comment: Let me elaborate: Say ID1 has the following rows: Direct, Direct, Some, Some, Direct. In this case, the output should be Some, Some, Some, Some, Direct. Meaning that all "Direct" rows before the first "Some" should be changed to "Some", but all "Direct" rows after that first "Some" should not be changed to "Some". Does this make sense?

Comment: @Guttulsrud - So if in `ID1` is `Direct, Direct, Some, Some, Direct, AAA, Direct` and ouput is `Some, Some, Some, Some, Direct, AAA, Direct`  ?